# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Incorrect integer value: '' for column `id16714481_casestudy_db`.`users`.`verified` at row 1

Tags: php, mysqli

I don't understand why this is happening even though I have classified $verified as a boolean on my bind_param.

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (user_name, email, verified, token, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ssbss', $username, $email, $verified, $token, $password);
```

Comment: For the bind data types - `b` is a blob.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a native boolean data type. Use `i` for parameter binding.

Answer (score 1):

Given the column name and the error message, I presume the `verified` column is an integer. However you're binding it as BLOB:

> - i   corresponding variable has type integer
> - d   corresponding variable has type double
> - s   corresponding variable has type string
> - b   corresponding variable is a blob and will be sent in packets

Both `i` and `s` should work.

([Reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php#refsect1-mysqli-stmt.bind-param-parameters))

Comment: Ohhh that's why it isn't working. Then why is it working on the Xampp MySQL?

Comment: Sorry, I've no idea of what "working on the Xampp MySQL" means.